# Paginate Table With Bootpag AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I found a plugin called Bootpag which provides some basic functions to paginate data.

I have a file which connects to a database and provides all the data in the table. The data is parsed into table rows and I want to append it to a

```
<tbody>
```

data.php

Holds the number of rows and the html

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory");
    $results->execute();
    $count = $results->rowCount();

    if($results->rowCount()==0) {
    echo 'No results where found';
    } else {
    echo $_POST[$count];
    while($data = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {  ?> 
        <tr class="invent">  
            <td><?php echo $data['wuno_product']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $data['wuno_alternates']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $data['wuno_description']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $data['wuno_onhand']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $data['wuno_condition']; ?></td>  
          </tr>  

         <?php
        }
      } 
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log('PDO Exception: '.$e->getMessage());
        die("ERROR: THERE WAS A PROBLEM CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE");
        }
```

In my user view file the data shows up if I include the file in but i am trying to get it and paginate it with an ajax call the html looks like this

```
 <table id="prods" class="display table center-table" width="100%" >
                    <thead>  
                            <tr>  
                                <th>Product #</th>  
                                <th>Alternate #</th>  
                                <th>Description</th>  
                                <th>On Hand</th>  
                            <th>Condition</th>
                            </tr>  
                        </thead>  

                    <tbody id="productResults"> 
                    <span class="pagination">

                    </span>
```

Finally I am using this Jquery to bring it all together but it won't load the data or sync it up with the pagination.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var assetPath ='<?php echo $assetPath; ?>';
var num ='<?php $_POST[$count];; ?>';
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('.pager-top,.pager-bottom').bootpag({
    total: 300,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 5,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: '←',
    last: '→',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'
}).on("page", function(event, num){
    $.ajax({
            url: "assetPath?pageNumber="+num,
            }).done(function(data) {
            $("#productResults").html( data );
             });
});
});
})( jQuery );

</script>
```

I am calling the variables I declare at the start of the Jquery to give me the page number and the path to the php script.

And here is a shot of the table with no data populated to give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. 
[image]

I am lost at this point I have not been able to figure out how to bring this together and have everything sync together. I look at tons of examples but I need specific information for my exact situation in order to better understand what logic I am not grasping to be able to complete these types of tasks.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question directly, since I have no experience with Bootpag. I do not want to suggest Bootpag is not a good solution. But my mind screams "Datatables"! https://www.datatables.net/ - it's what I use for these type of situations and Datatables works like a dream. You may want to consider it as an alternative.

Comment: I have tried everything you could possibly imagine and cant getting a working example up. I have all my data parsed in a function called showProducts(); All i need to do is figure out how to get that function to work with ajax in to the paginated table. If you think it is a good option please show me how to set it up

Comment: In my experience datatables works out of the box.. Just follow their instructions.. But i'm glad to be of help if you run into any issues! https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: @JeroenFlamman Hey, can you take a look at my question? It's about using Datatables, you can follow the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024686/how-to-implement-pagination-with-dynamic-html-table-data-via-ajax